# Pass argument to GNUPLOT config file

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Here is my gnuplot config file :

```
reset
set terminal png
set output "rp.png"
set title textcolor rgb "red" "R/P"
set yrange[0:110]
set xrange[0:110]
set xlabel "Rappel"
set ylabel "Précision"
set style data points
plot "test.dat" using 2:1 with linespoints
```

I would like to be able to replace at the last line "test.dat" by something like "filename" where "filename" would be passed.

For the moment I am just making this

```
FILE *gp;
 if(WIN32)
 {
   cout<<"Win 32"<<endl;
   
   gp=_popen("gnuplot", "w");
 }
 else
 {
   cout<<"pas win 32"<<endl;
   gp=popen("gnuplot", "w");
 }
 if(gp == NULL)
 {
   fprintf(stderr, "Oops, I can't find %s.");
   //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 fprintf(gp, "load \"config\"\n");
 fflush(gp); 
 pclose(gp);
```

but I have no idea on how to pass a parameter...

Comment: In your code there is nothing of Qt, QtCreator is an IDE that is different from Qt which is a library

Comment: I don't understand why you mention Qt, this just basic C++ code, unrelated to Qt.

Comment: Why don't you simply generate your gnuplot file from you C++ code ? That way you can have full control over it.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes ok thank you for editing

Comment: @kebs Could you explain me how to do ?

Comment: unrelated: if you want to use C++, then forget about `FILE` and use the standard library (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just set a variable containing the filename:

```
fprintf(gp, "filename=\"%s\";load \"config\"\n", file_name);
```

and then reuse it in your Gnuplot script:

```
reset
set terminal png
set output "rp.png"
set title textcolor rgb "red" "R/P"
set yrange[0:110]
set xrange[0:110]
set xlabel "Rappel"
set ylabel "Précision"
set style data points
plot filename using 2:1 with linespoints
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this enables you to have full control over what you need (sorry, quick and dirty, Linux only code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
   std::ofstream f("myfile.plt");
   f << "#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot\n";
   f << "reset\nset terminal pngcairo\n";
   //... the rest of what is needed
   std::string fn = "whatever.dat";
   f << "plot \"" << fn << "\" using 2:1 with linespoints\n";
   f.close();
   std::system( "chmod u+x myfile.plt" );
   std::system( "myfile.plt" );
}
```

(switch to the `pngcairo` terminal, produces much nicer output than `png`).

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, for passing arguments `ARG1`, `ARG2`, ... to gnuplot, you have the option `call` (check `help call`) or the command line option `-c` (check `help call example`).

**Data:** `SO53961356.dat`

```
1   0
2   5
3  10
4  15
5  20
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### arguments to gnuplot
reset session

set terminal pngcairo
set output ARG2

plot ARG1 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"
set output
### end of script
```

Either from the console type:

```
gnuplot -c SO53961356.gp SO53961356.dat SO53961356.png
```

or from the gnuplot console type:

```
call "SO53961356.gp" "SO53961356.dat" "SO53961356.png"
```

**Result:** `SO53961356.png`

[image]